# Modifying the layout of product options in both shopping cart page and Order review checkout section

Tags: layout, cart, template, magento-1, custom-options

I would like to display the product options differently  which appear:

- In the shopping cart page
- In the Checkout section "Order review"

Here are pictures showing what I need to do:

[image: Default Magento layout in shopping cart]

[image: Request Magento layout in shopping cart]

When we get through the checkout process, I have the same default layout in order review section.

What changes do I have to do to get the requested result?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I assumed, this is Magento 1, please update the question otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Change the file `template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` in your theme (if it does not exist, copy it from `base/default` first.

Look for `<dl class="item-options">`, this element contains the item options. You'll need to change the table layout, for example put the options in an own table row with `colspan`, to span over price, qty and subtotal.